# Delphi 10.4 Community Edition - inifile.ReadString does not return default value when it should ...?

Tags: delphi

Am I not seeing the forest for the trees?

Delphi returns `''` on `inifile.ReadString()` instead of the supplied default parameter. According to the help, it should return the default when either section, key, or value are missing.

I am pretty sure I have used this a number of times before without any issues before.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Classes, System.SysUtils, Inifiles, Dialogs;

implementation

const
  DRIVE_SECTION = 'USB_Drives';
  DRIVE_LETTER  = 'DriveLetter';
  INI_NAME      = 'c:\temp\test.ini';

//--------------------------------------------------------
procedure CreateDefaultInifile(const IniName: TFileName);
var
  slist: TStringList;
begin
  slist := TStringList.Create;
  try
    slist.Add('[' + DRIVE_SECTION + ']');
    slist.Add(DRIVE_LETTER + ' = ');
    //
    slist.SaveToFile(IniName);
  finally
    slist.Free;
  end;
end;

begin
  if not FileExists(INI_NAME) then
    CreateDefaultInifile(INI_NAME);
  // now we have an inifile with a key that has no value
  var ini := TIniFile.Create(INI_NAME);
  Showmessage(ini.ReadString(DRIVE_SECTION, DRIVE_LETTER, 'Missing_Value'));
  // according to Delphi's help, the default ('Missing_Value' in this case) should be returned if no value is assigned!
  ini.Free;
end.

end.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, your INI file looks like this:

```ini
[USB_Drives]
DriveLetter =
```

Clearly, there is a key named `DriveLetter`, and its value is the empty string.

Had the file instead been

```ini
[USB_Drives]
DriverFrogness =
```

you would indeed have received your `Missing_Value`, because then there isn't a `DriveLetter` key.

You apparently are under the impression that an empty string counts as a missing value. However, according to [the documentation for the `GetPrivateProfileString` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getprivateprofilestring), which the RTL's `TIniFile.ReadString()` is a thin wrapper around:

> `[in] lpDefault`
>
> A default string. If the *lpKeyName* key cannot be found in the initialization file, **GetPrivateProfileString** copies the default string to the *lpReturnedString* buffer.

Comment: Note that this behavior is the same for `TMemIniFile.ReadString()`, too.  The `Default` is not returned if the `Key` exists, whether its value is blank or not.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for [`TIniFile.ReadString()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IniFiles.TIniFile.ReadString) (and for [`TMemIniFile.ReadString()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IniFiles.TMemIniFile.ReadString), for that matter) is misleading. Specifically, the clause:

> `Default` is the string value to return if the:
>
> - ...
> - **Data value for the key is not assigned.**

is wrong, and needs to be removed. The `Default` value is returned only if the specified `Section` or `Key` is not found.  The *value* of the `Key` has no effect whatsoever on whether the `Default` is returned or not.

I have now filed a bug report with Embarcadero about this:

[RSP-39946: Docs for TIniFile.ReadString() and TMemIniFile.ReadString() are wrong.](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-39946)

Comment: Thanks Remy!  Much appreciated. I was wrong about thinking it ever worked. PureBasic's implementation does work that way, though.